# Using tabset in Angular, when hiding first tab the next tab loses tab outline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to read a flag from a configuration and then either show or hide tabs based on configuration on start up.
So far the hiding and showing is working for me. The problem is that if I hide the first tab, the next tab in line to show as the first tab, loses the tab outline.

So if I have three tabs 1, 2, 3 like this
[image]

If I hide 2 at startup, all is fine.
[image]

but if I hide 1 at startup, then 2 is missing the tab outline
[image]

My code does not toggle like in the example I provided below, but this is quickest, simplest example to show the problem. My code is similar and uses ng.show as well.

See example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cMROY3?p=preview
Please use the toggle button to see that when you switch to tab 2, the tab outline is missing.

html for given example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TabDemo">
      <tabset>
        <tab ng-show="!$parent.showTab">
          <tab-heading>1</tab-heading>
          test1
        </tab>
        <tab ng-show="$parent.showTab">
          <tab-heading>2</tab-heading>
          test2
        </tab>
      </tabset> 
      <p></p>showTab: {{showTab}}</p>
      <button ng-click="toggleTabs()">Toggle Tabs</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript for given example:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabDemo = function ($scope) {
  $scope.showTab = false;

  $scope.toggleTabs = function () {
    $scope.showTab = !$scope.showTab;
  };
};
```

Comment: The tab outline is enabled by the default angular-bootstrap CSS, on the tabs that has their `active` attribute evaluating to `true`. Read up on `active` in the [angular-bootstrap tab documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually did try setting active on the tab that will become the first tab after the hiding occurs and nothing is changing. I am hoping someone can give me a more narrowed down approach, possibly based on how they solved it.